# How can i make table headers fixed for a table populated using *ngFor Angular2 (without plug-ins)

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I tried to create different header and body and keep header as fixed , Iam able to keep headers as fixed but facing alignment issues. Below is my code

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-font" style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;margin-left:38px;width:97%!important">
   <thead class="blue-bg">
      <tr>
         <th>Header1</th>
         <th>Header2</th>
         <th>Header3</th>
         <th>Header4</th>
         <th>Header5</th>
         <th>Header6</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
<div class="child-grid no-flick" style="margin-left:38px;">
<table class="table table-bordered table-font">
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let RowData of datasource">  /*ngFor Used Here*/
      <td>   {{RowData.Data1}}</td>
      <td>   {{RowData.Data2}}</td>
      <td>   {{RowData.Data3}}</td>
      <td>   {{RowData.Data4}}</td>
      <td>   {{RowData.Data5}}</td>
      <td>   {{RowData.Data6}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.blue-bg {
    background-color: #4472C4;
    color: white;
}

.child-grid{
    max-height:500px !important;
    overflow-y:scroll!important;
}


.no-flick{
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    .table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Iam facing allignment issues like  this

[image: Border of <th> and <tr> arent matching]

Please help or suggest me any other method that can be used for having fixed headers in a table with ngFor

Comment: Why are your table headers in a separate table?

Comment: its a scrolabble page, i needed fixed headers so i choose this approach

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, but every way has its own pros and cons which depend on your usecase. Thats why giving a `good` answer is hard since you don't describe the features you want. Furthermore, i don't see how this has anything to do with the `ngFor` directive. So before i go and give you a solution, please try to be more specific. Do you have a table in a seperate container with its own scrollbars, do you plan on having fixed columns, is the widht of your table dynamic, are the column widths dynamic? Just a few things to think about for you to improve your question.

Comment: i have container with scroll and table column width is responsive, thats where iam facing the problem, column widths dont match.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a plug-in for this, I have used these with good results, check out the links below.

http://www.fixedheadertable.com/
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Comment: i dont want plugins, and this is not jQuery, i am using angular2

Comment: Ok Amarnath, please mention this when writing your question be clear to other users that you dont want to use plug-ins, Also I did not mention in my post that this was in anyway JQuery.

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy are you open to using CSS to fix this?

Comment: @garek007 yes please help

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy why not then just set some CSS for td,th{width:16.6666%;} or something like that? depending on how many columns you have you may need to change that, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS to set the width of the table to 100% and the width of the cells to divide by 100. You have 6 cells so 100/6 = 16.6666%. See the [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/th00jgjL/)
I had to remove your div and your inline styles because they were breaking this, but you can add them back in around this CSS. You also probably don't need the border, but I put it there so you can see it works.

```
table{
  width:100%;
}
td,th{
  width:16.66%;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}
```